# How to subscribe to changes image

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have own image class (UICustomImage).

How to track changes to pictures and update GLKView?

**ViewModel:**

```
final class ViewModel {

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let image: UICustomImage
let sliderValue: Variable<Float>

init(image: UIImage) {

    self.sliderValue = Variable(Float(0.0))

    self.image = UICustomImage(image: image)        

    self.sliderValue.asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            self.image.brightness(n: value)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

}
```

**ViewController:**

```
@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
private var viewModel: ViewModel!

var image: UIImage?

override viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel = ViewModel(image: image!)

    slider.rx.value
        .subscribe(onNext: { value in
            self.viewModel.sliderValue.value = value
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I want the picture to be updated when the slider moves.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Is it not working?

Comment: @shpasta This code works. I do not know how to subscribe to picture changes.

Comment: I don't know what is inside of your CustomImage class, but you can observe its properties with KVO, like image.rx.observe(Float.self, "brightness").subscribe(onNext: { brightness in ... }) , in case if brightness is a Float property of CustomImage class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your brightened image as an Observable. This would be much simpler if you made your `brightness(n:)` function an extension on UIImage instead of making a custom class...

Some notes:

- ViewModels do *not* need dispose bags. If you are putting one in your view model, you are probably doing something wrong.
- I assumed that `UICustomImage` could return an updated `UIImage` by calling `asImage`.
- I assumed that `brightness(n:)` did not return a value.

Note how I made `image` a dependent variable on `sliderValue`.

```
final class ViewModel {

    let image: Observable<UIImage>
    let sliderValue: Variable<Float>

    init(image: UIImage) {

        sliderValue = Variable(Float(0.0))

        self.image = sliderValue.asObservable()
            .map { let image = UICustomImage(image: image)
                image.brightness(n: $0)
                return image.asImage
            }
    }
}
```

Notes on the view controller:

- You forgot to call `super.viewDidLoad()`. You must always do that.
- I made `image` implicitly unwrapped. Might as well since the code would have crashed without an image in any case.
- I converted your subscribe into a bind. It looks cleaner.

Once you have made your viewModel's image property an observable, then all you need to do is bind it to your image view.

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private var viewModel: ViewModel!

    var image: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel = ViewModel(image: image)

        slider.rx.value
            .bind(to: viewModel.sliderValue)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.image
            .bind(to: imageView.rx.image)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```